# Cant see all members in Object (but with `OfType` I can access)

Tags: c#, types

There are "Cat", "Dog","Zebra" (and many)  in `MyAnimals` (I don't have access to code where it is defined):

```
foreach (var x in MyAnimals){
   Print( (x as Animal).Type);
}
```

Only 2 of them is outputed (`Cat` and `Dog`, and many nulls). If I use `MyAnimals.OfType<Zebra>()` , then it sees `Zebra` too.

1) How that is possible, that first loop  can't see all members ?

2) How can I get iterate/all contained objects, without manually using `oftype()` for every other object?

Comment: Code that (actually) compiles and reproduces this problem is needed.

Comment: @spender I don't have an access. If you have any idea, that's good, if not, don't mind.

Comment: @Rahul don't have an access. If you have any idea, that's good, if not, don't mind.

Comment: You don't get any null reference exceptions?

Comment: Most likely, the Zebra class did not override the Type property. That would explain why you may not see Zebra printed out, but can obviously find the object in your collection. Does *anything* print out when the Zebra class is printed?

Comment: What is MyAnimals? You should have access to that...

Comment: @MongZhu yes, i have! you're smart, probably thats my issue!

Comment: @TylerLee if you posted answer, i will upvote that, as it's answer to my question probably!  (bt, it prints null too, but dont know if that's or not)

Comment: That would actually mean that `zebra` does not inherit from `Animal`

Comment: but why `ofType()` works then? how can I get all other animals, that may be in `Animals` but I still dont know?   there should be some code, to get all those animals. 

btw.please post as answer, i will accept that is the most correct for this.

Comment: If there is no Inheritance relationship then zebra is not an animal in this case. You would have to query your collection twice. Once for all animals and once for the zebra extra

Comment: What type does the collection contain? `object`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170816/discussion-between-mong-zhu-and-t-todua).

Comment: @MongZhu sorry for incorrect pronuncation (i am new to c#). I mean, lets say, i want to get all of the existing classes from `MyAnimals` (doesnt matter if inherited from  `Animal` class or not... I want to iterate in all of them, with one call), how that's possible? using `(x as object)` ?

Comment: @T.Todua **With respect**, your question does have serious flaws and could _easily_ use some improvements on your part. If I were you, I would focus on that instead of attacking _downvoters_. You've been here long enough to know better than that. Again **with respect**, you have 38 downvoted questions (almost quarter your total questions) ranging between -1 and -9, do you think people are just against you for no reason? Or maybe your questions do need improvements? I hope you don't find my comment/advice offensive, and good luck :)

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed no ahmed, thanks for the comment really. Just look through my other questions, and maybe you will think same.  i am newbie in C#, and have legitimate questions. (even other commenters say that when they see my downvoted quetions). But you could be right in some way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get a NullReferenceException when casting to `Animal` then it means that `Zebra` is not a derived class. Although it seems to have a similar structure as the other classes

Comment: @T.Todua The classes aren't null, its the cast to Animal that returns null when it is not of the type Animal (when it is Zebra). You'll have to check the type of the object before casting to know what to cast it to.

Comment: @BlakeThingstad good explanation. I understand now. upvoting you.

Comment: @T.Todua Glad to help =)

Comment: @T.Todua I will Edit my answer tomorrow and add the suggestions I gave you in the chat to make the answer complete. Gotta sleep now. Cheers mate

Answer (score 1):

My guess (without being able to see the code) is that the Zebra class did not override the Type property. That would explain why you may not see Zebra printed out, but can obviously find the object in your collection.